# How would a boxplot of an normal distribution for probability look like?

Tags: statistics

If I were to plot the probabilities for a normal distribution what would the boxplot looks like? Would it always be symmetric for every parameter value?

Comment: Yes, it will always be symmetric. This is because the boxplot tries to give an idea of where the quantiles are or the dispersion of your data. The Gaussian density is always symmetric around its mean, for any parameters. The only thing that can change is how disperse your data is, which indicates high or low variance. Of course, the mean (or location) can also change, which indicates where your data is centered.

Answer (score 0):

A Boxplot only makes sense if we draw some sample. So, let us assume that we draw a sample of size $n$ from a normal distribution with mean $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and variance $\sigma^2>0$.

If you mean by a symmetric boxplot that the median is at the midpoint between the lower and upper quartile (i.e., in the middle of the box) and the whiskers have the same length, then the answer is yes if you pick $n$ large enough to ensure you get a "typical sample". The reason is that the normal distribution is always symmetric. Hence, the median and mean coincide etc.

Here is an example for $n=100,000$, $\mu=\pi$ and $\sigma=e$.
[image]

If you want to try it out yourself and know R, here is the code that produced the above picture:

```
n <- 100000  # sample size
mu <- pi # mean
sigma2 <- exp(1) # variance
boxplot(rnorm(1:n, mean = mu, sd = sqrt(sigma2)), horizontal = TRUE)
```